# How to prove this series converges uniformly?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

For this series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{e^{x^2}+\sqrt{n}}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}},$$ I have no idea how to prove it converges uniformly in $[a,b]$. Can't even tell what does it converge to. I can just figure out that $$(-1)^n \frac{e^{x^2}+\sqrt{n}}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ converges to zero but have no idea what it is when it is summed up.

Can anybody help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well isn't it the same as $$
\mathrm{e}^{x^2 } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n^{3/2} }}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{n}} ?
$$

Comment: I assume $x$ is bounded.

Comment: @Yimin ur right sorry I've lost that.

Comment: @Gary yes but forgive my slow reaction I haven't got the point.

Comment: @berryx https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Alternating_series_estimation_theorem

Comment: @Gary ohh is it right that since $\mathrm{e}^{x^2}$ is bounded, so the two parts are all converges to 0 which has nothing to do with x?

Comment: @berryx The sums converge to *non-zero* values. Your goal is to estimate the tail of the series.

Comment: @Gary oh. using Cauchy you mean?

Comment: @Gary why does it converges to a none zero values? :(

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n^{3/2} }}}  = (2^{ - 1/2}  - 1)\zeta (3/2) =  - 0.7651 \ldots ,\quad \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{n}}  =  - \log 2 =  - 0.6931 \ldots 
$$ The Wikipedia link I gave you tells you exactly how to estimate the remainder of this type of alternating series.

Comment: @Gary ok thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Gary's comment, first see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ is just a convergent series of real numbers and has nothing to do with $x$. So you need not bother with that.

Secondly, $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|\frac{(-1)^{n}e^{x^{2}}}{n\sqrt{n}}|\leq C|\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}|$ where $C=\max(e^{a^{2}},e^{b^{2}})$

And $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converges. Thus, by Weirestrass M-test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}e^{x^{2}}}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converges uniformly over $x\in[a,b]$ and that's it.

**Warning/Caution:** First you have to show the steps that I did above. Only then you can write $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{e^{x^2}+\sqrt{n}}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}e^{x^{2}}}{n\sqrt{n}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$$ and then conclude uniform convergence not the otherway around!!!. If you are confused by this, then perhaps it is wise to ponder over it for a while.

Comment: The second series should contain $1/n$ and not $1/\sqrt n$.

Comment: @Gary Ah thanks. Silly typo.

Comment: ah thanks a lot!